# How To Sort FetchedResultsController By Measurement Foundation Class, Formerly: Core Data Crash While Saving

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am having a strange crash while saving new data into Core Data. The relevant portions of the structure are as follows:

```
struct ParachuteDataController {

let databaseController = DatabaseController()
let context = DatabaseController().getContext()

    func addParachute(newParachute: ParachuteData) {

        let parachute = Parachute(context: context)

        parachute.setValue(newParachute.diameter, forKey: CoreData.diameter)
        parachute.setValue(newParachute.area, forKey: CoreData.area) //Measurement
        parachute.setValue(newParachute.dragCoefficient, forKey: CoreData.dragCoefficient) //Measurement
        parachute.setValue(newParachute.mass, forKey: CoreData.mass) //Measurement
        parachute.setValue(newParachute.material.rawValue, forKey: CoreData.material) //String
        parachute.setValue(newParachute.measurementType.rawValue, forKey: CoreData.measurementType)
        parachute.setValue(newParachute.shape.rawValue, forKey: CoreData.shape) //String
        parachute.setValue(newParachute.vented, forKey: CoreData.vented) //Bool
        if newParachute.vented {
            parachute.setValue(newParachute.ventDiameter, forKey: CoreData.ventDiameter)//Optional Measurement
        }

        saveInCoreData()
    }

    private func saveInCoreData() {

        do {
            try DatabaseController().getContext().save()
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

class DatabaseController: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = DatabaseController()

    override init() {}

    public func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {

        return DatabaseController.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    public var fetchPredicate : NSPredicate?

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Recovery")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext

        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {

                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CoreData is simply a constant Struct.

My model has attributes for each of the listed items in addParachute. When I try to add all of the items to the Core Data model, I get the following crash:

> NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[NSMeasurement compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c04211e0 with userInfo (null)
>   2018-04-03 08:28:48.533419-0400 Recovery[1210:643911] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSMeasurement compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

If I pull out any ONE item of the attributes, it saves fine. It does not matter which item it is. I can't even narrow it down to any particular attribute as a result. I have other entities which save measurements, set up essentially identically and there are no problems.

Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I am on the right track as to the actual cause of my crash thanks to this post:
[Extremely Odd Crash When saving a transformable NSAttributedString into Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726500/extremely-odd-crash-when-saving-a-transformable-nsattributedstring-into-core-dat?rq=1).

I hadn't found it earlier as it is an Objective C question. However, the underlying issue is the same: my FetchedResultsController updating as a result of the Core Data save.

In my View Controller class, I have the following function:

```
 func configureFetchedResultsController() {
    let context = databaseController.getContext()
    let parachutesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Parachute>(entityName: CoreData.parachute)
    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: CoreData.material, ascending: true)
    let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "diameter.value", ascending: true)

    let sortDescriptor = [primarySortDescriptor, secondarySortDescriptor]
    parachutesFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptor

    self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Parachute>(
        fetchRequest: parachutesFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: CoreData.material,
        cacheName: nil)

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

}
```

The cause of the crash is `let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "diameter", ascending: true)`. diameter is a Measurement and this does not seem to play well with the FRC's sorting. When I changed the code to `let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "diameter.value", ascending: true)` in hopes of having it sort by the value, I get the following error:

> NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key value. with userInfo {
>       NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = " value: 0.304800 unit: m";
>       NSUnknownUserInfoKey = value; }

Is it possible to sort by a Measurement and, if so, how?

Thanks for all who provided suggest that helped me narrow the issue.

Comment: In your `saveInCoreData()`  try to replace `DatabaseController().getContext().save()` with `context` may that works

Comment: I actually had tried that at one point. I have also correct the DatabaseController to vend a singleton as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I indicated in the edit, the issue had nothing to do with the Core Data save. The crash is caused once the save occurs and the FetchedResultsController(frc) is updated. It is resorted based on my sortDescriptors, one of which is a Measurement. While I have not been able to determine what, if any, syntax is necessary to sort on the Measurement, sorting on another attribute in Core Data prevents the crash. For someone looking into this in the future, I tried sorting on the Measurement itself and the value of the measurement, both of which caused runtime crashes. So, I am marking this question as solved for my initial question.

If you get a crash due to a compare statement, look to your frc as the cause.